# How to fit a distribution to an existing CDF in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I am woking on a project to understand the distribution of different elevations in a landscape. This requires me to measure how many data points of each elevation there are in a raster (each pixel = one elevation value). Given my mapped area is large, I end up with very large frequency counts of each election. I have a distribution of data that looks something like this:

```
Elevation, Frequency  
0, 89021  
0.01, 56893  
0.02, 39504   
0.03, 35894 
...
```

Now, I've gone ahead and calculated my own CDF for these values based on the frequency count of values. I am trying to fit a distribution to this CDF. I am aware of fitdist packages, but these seem to compute the CDF from raw measurements, and so would not work with my data unless I make a file with 89021 rows of 0, then 56893 rows of 0.01 etc...This is really impractical. Is there a way to fit a distribution to an already provided CDF? Thanks!

Additional Details:
My elevation values are:

```
elev = c(0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 
    0.009, 0.01, 0.011, 0.012, 0.013, 0.014, 0.015, 0.016, 0.017, 
    0.018, 0.019, 0.02, 0.021, 0.022, 0.023, 0.024)
```

The number of measurements of each elevation value are:

```
count = c(415348, 162928, 73967, 81997, 54291, 57883, 36105, 
   49516, 33736, 37557, 39057, 41544, 27860, 20015, 20367, 
   19158, 19960, 15577, 1452, 9888, 3851, 2238, 157)
```

I have taken my frequency measurements and converted them to % smaller than values. The result is a vector of:

```
cumulative = c(0.3357563, 0.4674630, 0.5272559, 0.5935401, 
   0.6374275, 0.6842186, 0.7134049, 0.7534324, 0.7807036, 0.8110637, 
   0.8426364, 0.8762194, 0.8987407, 0.9149203, 0.9313845, 0.9468713, 
   0.9630064, 0.9755984, 0.9869577, 0.9949509, 0.9980639, 0.9998731, 
   1.0000000, 1.0000000)
```

[image: This is what the distribution looks like].

I wish to fit a distribution function to these values if possible.

Comment: You say that you have "gone ahead and calculated my own CDF for these values". In what form do you have the CDF?  Can you give us an example of what you have so that we can work from the same starting point as you?

Comment: Added details as edits to the original post. Hope that help!

Comment: statistically, it makes the most sense to fit a multinomial distribution to the vector of the number of counts in each **non-cumulative** bin, with the probability of falling in each bin determined by the probability, according to your theoretical distribution, of falling between the lower and upper limits of the bin (i.e. if you have a continuous distribution, CDF(upper)-CDF(lower))

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand R has a multinomial distribution function (dmultinon), but this outputs a single value. How would I be able to then plot this as a line?

Comment: Do you want to fit a distribution to these values?  If so,  what form of distribution are you looking for?  Or do you really only need to generate more points that roughly follow the same distribution?

Comment: EllieP, what is the already-provided CDF which you mentioned?

Comment: @BenBolker OP says they have an already-provided CDF. It seems therefore that the problem is to estimate parameters for said CDF given the empirical CDF, which is just the cumulative frequency counts. That problem can be easily solved by a slight generalization of the usual maximum likelihood method. I don't see a multinomial distribution in this picture.

Comment: @RobertDodier: I'm not clear on how one fits an a theoretical CDF to an empirical CDF (I can only see easily how to fit a theoretical distribution to a binned distribution of counts), so if you do, go for it ...

Comment: As @RobertDodier mentioned - the values provide an empirical CDF for which I am trying to fit a theoretical function. How would one go about generalizing a maximum likelihood method? Thanks!

Comment: Hi EllieP, it would really others help you if you would just say what the theoretical CDF is. I can go into details after that.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what function would work best, but my guess based on the data is that it likely fits a Weibull distribution. I feel that perhaps my initial question was misunderstood. When I say I've calculated a CDF, I do not have a function - rather the cumulative frequency counts.

Answer (score 1):

Data for which you only know the number of data falling into intervals are censored data. In general, whatever the theoretical CDF, the likelihood function is a product of terms like

```
(probability of falling into the k`th interval)^(number of data in that interval)
```

where the probability is just

```
CDF(right end of k`th interval) - CDF(left end of k`th interval)
```

You can get the Weibull CDF for each endpoint from a function or just write it out. Given that the intervals are contiguous, the probability is

```
CDF(x[k + 1]) - CDF(x[k])
```

where the x[k] is the list of endpoints. (You'll need to be careful about the last interval.) So the likelihood function is

```
product ((CDF(x[k + 1]) - CDF(x[k]))^n[k], k, 0, nintervals - 1)
```

and the log likelihood is

```
sum (n[k]*log(CDF(x[k + 1]) - CDF(x[k])), k, 0, nintervals - 1)
```

It's probably not a bad idea to scale the log likelihood so that the factors are not so big. Scaling doesn't change the location of the maximum likelihood parameters so that's OK. I'll divide by (total n).

```
sum ((n[k]/(total n))*log(CDF(x[k + 1]) - CDF(x[k])), k, 0, nintervals - 1)
```

Now n[k]/(total n) = p[k] where p[k] is the proportion falling into the k'th interval. That gives the log likelihood a pleasing entropy-like form,

```
sum (p[k]*log(CDF(x[k + 1]) - CDF(x[k])), k, 0, nintervals - 1)
```

At this point you can plug in the Weibull CDF formula and apply a numerical minimizer to it. From looking at your data, it seems like scale > 1 and shape < 1, so maybe pick initial values scale = 2 and shape = 1/2 or something. (I'm looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution for that.)

EDIT: I gave it a try with an implementation of LBFGS in Maxima. No doubt there's something like that in Python or R. NOTE: the summation I showed above the log likelihood, which you want to maximize. However, many numerical routines want to *minimize*, so supply the negative of the log likelihood.

I replaced `elev` with 100 times `elev`, so the range of value is 0 to 2.4 instead of 0 to 0.024. I found that helps LBFGS find a minimum.

With initial guess of shape = 0.3, scale = 1, I found the approximate solution shape = 1.185, scale = 0.609. (Again, note the scale is 100 times the original scale.) Plotting the Weibull CDF seems to show a picture which agrees with the empirical CDF plot.

Finally, the approximation I mentioned can probably be implemented by replacing `x[k]` with `p[k]*x[k]` in the formulas for maximum likelihood estimation as shown on the wiki page. However, I wasn't able to prove that, after looking at the formulas for a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This may be more advanced stats than what I'm familiar with, but will give it a try!

Comment: Thanks for your interest. An approximation which is probably going to work well, given that the intervals are small compared to the whole range, is to replace (CDF(x[k + 1]) - CDF(x[k])) with PDF(x[k]) times (x[k + 1] - x[k]), i.e. mass in interval is approximated by rectangle. That gives a weighted version of the conventional likelihood function. You can try it -- I might be able to work on it today or tomorrow.

Comment: @EllieP I added some more notes about the approximate solution I got. Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow I only got back to this now! Thanks so much for taking the time to get this to work. I'll take a look at it more closely tomorrow and see if I can replicate some of this. Cheers!